# [HDFS connector + Kafka]How to write multiple topics in standalone mode?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using `Confluent`'s `HDFS Connector` to write streamed data to `HDFS`. I followed the user manual and [quick start](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html#quickstart) and setup my Connector.
It works properly when i consume only one topic.
My property file looks like this

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test_topic1
hdfs.url=hdfs://localhost:9000
flush.size=30
```

When i add more than one topic, i see it continuously committing offsets and i do not see it writing the committed messages.

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=2
topics=test_topic1,test_topic2
hdfs.url=hdfs://localhost:9000
flush.size=30
```

I tried with tasks.max with 1 and 2. 
I continuously get `Committing offsets` logged as below

```
[2016-10-26 15:21:30,990] INFO Started recovery for topic partition test_topic1-0 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter:193)
[2016-10-26 15:21:31,222] INFO Finished recovery for topic partition test_topic1-0 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter:208)
[2016-10-26 15:21:31,230] INFO Started recovery for topic partition test_topic2-0 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter:193)
[2016-10-26 15:21:31,236] INFO Finished recovery for topic partition test_topic2-0 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter:208)
[2016-10-26 15:21:35,155] INFO Reflections took 6962 ms to scan 249 urls, producing 11712 keys and 77746 values  (org.reflections.Reflections:229)
[2016-10-26 15:22:29,226] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:261)
[2016-10-26 15:23:29,227] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:261)
[2016-10-26 15:24:29,225] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:261)
[2016-10-26 15:25:29,224] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:261)
```

When i gracefully stop the service (Ctrl+C), i see it removing the `tmp` files.
What am i doing wrong? What is the proper way to do it?
Appreciate any suggestions on this.

Comment: Can you share the result of ```$ hadoop fs -ls /topics```?

Comment: Found 3 items
    drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-11-17 12:29 /topics/+tmp
    drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-11-16 17:29 /topics/test_topic1
    drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-11-16 17:32 /topics/test_topic2

Answer (score 2):

I've kept stumbling over the same problem you've mentioned here for the past month or so and I couldn't get to the bottom of it, until today when I've upgraded to [confluent 3.1.1](http://packages.confluent.io/archive/3.1/confluent-3.1.1-2.11.tar.gz) and stuff started working as expected...

This is how I roll

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=5
topics=accounts,contacts,users
hdfs.url=hdfs://localhost:9000
flush.size=1
hive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:9083
hive.integration=true
schema.compatibility=BACKWARD
format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner
locale=en-us
timezone=UTC
```